# How to update DeltaY clock in three.js on scroll (top/bottom)

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have an animation prototype - which plays on scroll - is there a way to reset animation on scroll to top/bottom? Basically from the top it plays and stops when it reaches the bottom? Right now the animation loops and ignores top/bottom (start/end).

When scrolled from the top it plays forward and when reached the bottom it plays in reverse is the desired bahaviour.

```js
 var container, stats, controls;
      var camera, scene, renderer, light;
      var clock = new THREE.Clock();

      var mixer = [];

      var mixers = [];

      init();

      animate();

      function init() {

        container = document.createElement( 'div' );
        document.body.appendChild( container );

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
        camera.position.set( 0, 100, 100 );

        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        light = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xffffff, 0x444444 );
        light.position.set( 0, 200, 0 );
        scene.add( light );

        light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
        light.position.set( 0, 200, 100 );
        light.castShadow = true;
        light.shadow.camera.top = 180;
        light.shadow.camera.bottom = -100;
        light.shadow.camera.left = -120;
        light.shadow.camera.right = 120;
        scene.add( light );

          // scene.add( new THREE.CameraHelper( light.shadow.camera ) );

          var grid = new THREE.GridHelper( 2000, 20, 0x000000, 0x000000 );
          grid.material.opacity = 0.2;
          grid.material.transparent = true;
          scene.add( grid );

          // model
          var loader = new THREE.FBXLoader();
          loader.load( 'https://threejs.org/examples/models/fbx/Samba Dancing.fbx', function ( object ) {

            object.mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( object );
            mixers.push( object.mixer );


            var action = object.mixer.clipAction( object.animations[ 0 ] );
            action.play();


            object.traverse( function ( child ) {

              if ( child.isMesh ) {

                child.castShadow = true;
                child.receiveShadow = true;

              }

            } );
            object.position.y = 85;

            scene.add( object );

          } );


          renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { alpha: true, antialias: true } );
          renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
          renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
          renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
          container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

          window.addEventListener( 'mousewheel', onMouseWheel, false );
          window.addEventListener( 'touchstart', onTouchStart, false );
          window.addEventListener( 'touchmove', onTouchMove, false );

          window.addEventListener('resize', onResize, false);

          // stats
          stats = new Stats();
          container.appendChild( stats.dom );

        }


        function onResize() {
          camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
          camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
          renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        }


        function onMouseWheel( event ) {


          if(event.deltaY > 0){
            for ( var i = 0; i < mixers.length; i ++ ) {
              mixers[ i ].update( clock.getDelta() * 5 );
            }
          } else {
            for ( var i = 0; i < mixers.length; i ++ ) {
              mixers[ i ].update( clock.getDelta() * -5 );

            }
          }
        }


        function onTouchStart(event) {

          startY = event.touches[ 0 ].pageY;


        }

        function onTouchMove( event ) {

          var delta = event.deltaY;

          if(event.deltaY > 0){
            for ( var i = 0; i < mixers.length; i ++ ) {
              mixers[ i ].update( clock.getDelta() * 5 );
            }
          } else {
            for ( var i = 0; i < mixers.length; i ++ ) {
              mixers[ i ].update( clock.getDelta() * -5 );

            }
          }


        }


        function animate() {

         delta = clock.getDelta();

         requestAnimationFrame( animate );

         renderer.render( scene, camera );

         stats.update();

       }
```

```css
body {

        margin: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
```

```html
     <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
       <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
      <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/inflate.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/FBXLoader.js"></script>
         <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/WebGL.js"></script>
          <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

First off you should **never link directly to threejs.org**. Your example will break when the three.js devs update the version which will make your question example useless to others. Use a specific version from a [CDN](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/three)!

Otherwise if you save off the clips

```
                object.mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( object );
                mixers.push( object.mixer );


                const clip = object.animations[0];
                clips.push(clip);
                var action = object.mixer.clipAction(clip);
                action.play();
```

Then maybe you could use code like this

```
        function updateAnimation(direction) {
          const delta = direction * 5 * clock.getDelta();
          for (let i = 0; i < mixers.length; ++i) {
            const mixer = mixers[i];
            const clip = clips[i];
            const duration = clip.duration;
            const newTime = THREE.MathUtils.clamp(mixer.time + delta, 0, duration);
            mixer.setTime(newTime);
          }
        }


        function onMouseWheel( event ) {
          updateAnimation(Math.sign(event.deltaY)); 
        }

...
```

```js
var container, stats, controls;
      var camera, scene, renderer, light;
      var duration;
      var clock = new THREE.Clock();

      var mixer = [];

      var mixers = [];
      var clips = [];

      init();

      animate();

      function init() {

        container = document.createElement( 'div' );
        document.body.appendChild( container );

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
        camera.position.set( 0, 100, 100 );

        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        light = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xffffff, 0x444444 );
        light.position.set( 0, 200, 0 );
        scene.add( light );

        light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
        light.position.set( 0, 200, 100 );
        light.castShadow = true;
        light.shadow.camera.top = 180;
        light.shadow.camera.bottom = -100;
        light.shadow.camera.left = -120;
        light.shadow.camera.right = 120;
        scene.add( light );

          // scene.add( new THREE.CameraHelper( light.shadow.camera ) );

          var grid = new THREE.GridHelper( 2000, 20, 0x000000, 0x000000 );
          grid.material.opacity = 0.2;
          grid.material.transparent = true;
          scene.add( grid );

          // model
          var loader = new THREE.FBXLoader();
          loader.load( 'https://threejs.org/examples/models/fbx/Samba Dancing.fbx', function ( object ) {

            object.mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( object );
            mixers.push( object.mixer );


            const clip = object.animations[0];
            clips.push(clip);
            var action = object.mixer.clipAction(clip);
            action.play();


            object.traverse( function ( child ) {

              if ( child.isMesh ) {

                child.castShadow = true;
                child.receiveShadow = true;

              }

            } );
            object.position.y = 85;

            scene.add( object );

          } );


          renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { alpha: true, antialias: true } );
          renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
          renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
          renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
          container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

          window.addEventListener( 'mousewheel', onMouseWheel, false );


          window.addEventListener('resize', onResize, false);

          // stats
          stats = new Stats();
          container.appendChild( stats.dom );

        }


        function onResize() {
          camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
          camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
          renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        }
        
        function updateAnimation(direction) {
          const delta = direction * 5 * clock.getDelta();
          for (let i = 0; i < mixers.length; ++i) {
            const mixer = mixers[i];
            const clip = clips[i];
            const duration = clip.duration;
            const newTime = THREE.MathUtils.clamp(mixer.time + delta, 0, duration);
            mixer.setTime(newTime);
          }
        }


        function onMouseWheel( event ) {
          updateAnimation(Math.sign(event.deltaY)); 
        }


        function animate() {

         delta = clock.getDelta();

         requestAnimationFrame( animate );

         renderer.render( scene, camera );

         stats.update();

       }
```

```css
body {

        margin: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.113.2/build/three.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.113.2/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.113.2/examples/js/libs/inflate.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.113.2/examples/js/loaders/FBXLoader.js"></script>
         <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.113.2/examples/js/WebGL.js"></script>
          <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.113.2/examples/js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It works - how would it be on mobile - touch -    window.addEventListener( 'touchstart', onTouchStart, false );
          window.addEventListener( 'touchmove', onTouchMove, false );